# circular dependency between items. :app.progressDebugResources

Tags: circular-dependency

ircular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:processDebugResources
--- :app:processDebugResources (*)

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.CircularReferenceException: Circular dependency between the following tasks:
  :app:processDebugResources
  --- :app:processDebugResources (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)

```
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DetermineExecutionPlanAction.onOrderingCycle(DetermineExecutionPlanAction.java:295)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DetermineExecutionPlanAction.processNodeQueue(DetermineExecutionPlanAction.java:187)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DetermineExecutionPlanAction.run(DetermineExecutionPlanAction.java:93)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.determineExecutionPlan(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:223)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:67)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$8(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:189)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:99)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:114)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:189)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:169)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildController.java:76)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraphBuilder.withWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:41)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph$1.run(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:209)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph.scheduleWork(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:37)
at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController$scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks$1.apply(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:36)
at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController$scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks$1.apply(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:35)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:112)
at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController.scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:35)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$scheduleAndRunTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:77)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:120)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:117)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:77)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:72)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:123)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:92)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:71)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
```